# How to determine d in this RSA Algorithm Example?

Tags: algorithm, cryptography, rsa

As part of my college course I have been given a question to solve. It is on the topic of the RSA Algorithm.

I have been given p = 29, q = 17 and e = 5.

I have to determine d.

So I know n = 29 x 17 => 493 and phi(n) = 448

So I get down to the point where I know

```
5 * d mod 448 = 1
```

I then follow the Euclidean Algorithm to get to

```
448 = 89(5) + 3
```

With 3 being the remainder (quotient) there. In previous examples I done where the quotient ended up being 1, it was very easy to solve what d was. However, I have no idea how to do it for this example with the remainder being 3.

Does anyone know how to do this? Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: That's the thing, I'm not allowed pick another. I was given e = 5 in the question and am restricted to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't finish the extended euclidean algorithm. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)

You should have `(r_i, s_i, t_i)`:

```
(448,1,0)    =>  1*448   + 0*5 = 448
(5, 0, 1)    =>  0*448   + 1*5 =   5
(3, 1, -89)  =>  1*448  - 89*5 =   3
(2, -1, 90)  => -1*448  + 90*5 =   2
(1, 2, -179) =>  2*448 - 179*5 =   1
```

You can check to see that `2*448 - 179*5 = 1`,  so `-179 * 5 = 1 mod 448`, or `269*5 = 1 mod 448`, and your answer is `d = 269`

Comment: But 5 * d mod 448 has to equal 1 must it not?